# Editing labeling call out boxes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling

I am trying to get labels that look like the image below

[image: example of label i am trying to replicate]

I have been able to come up with something similar. however the leader arrow takes on the callout box boundary properties. as seen in the image below

[image: current look of label]

How can I go about this?

I am working with ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2

Answer (score 2):

You have to drill deep into the symbol editor to create a similar effect. Below is a screenshot of which buttons you need to navigate. Eventually you need to add another layer to the symbol, in this case another fill which is white and has a thicker outline. This will give it the halo effect, but it will also apply to the leader.

[image: Symbol editor]

You end with something like this:

[image: Callout label]

Comment: Rather than using the fallout button. You might be able to use the leader and configure a text box.